# RXJS Why only the last number has both a and b?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable

I saw the following code:

```js
var source = Rx.Observable
  .range(1, 3)
  .flatMapLatest(function(x) {
    return Rx.Observable.from([x + 'a', x + 'b']);
  });

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
    document.body.innerHTML += 'Next: ' + x + '<br>';
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
    document.body.innerHTML += 'Completed';
  });

// Next: 1a
// Next: 2a
// Next: 3a
// Next: 3b
// Completed
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

I wanted to understand why only 3/last value has both a and b.

Basically I am still having difficulties understanding the Rx.Observable.from with the array as a parameter.

Thanks,
Saar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is completed to explain. This behavior has more to do with `flatMapLatest` and `range` that it has to do with `from`.

Basically `range(1,3)` emits **synchronously** its three items. Then `flatMapLatest` will emit in that same tick only the first value `'x'+a`. Before it emits the second value, it needs to close already that observable because a new value from `range` has arrived and it needs to produce the new corresponding observable (you know that `flatMapLatest` when a new value arrives closes the current observable and produces the new one. That's the meaning of `latest` isn't it).

This goes like this till the last value (`3`) in the case of which there is no new value, hence the `from` observable can emit its full list of values.

Some extra helpful links:

- [marble for flatMapLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

> The flatMapLatest operator behaves much like the standard FlatMap operator, except that whenever a new item is emitted by the source Observable, it will unsubscribe to and stop mirroring the Observable that was generated from the previously-emitted item, and begin only mirroring the current one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I hope I understand it now. please correct me if i'm wrong. Since the range is a synchronous array (all of the values are already available) it emits them one of the other without stopping, this meaning that for each value the observable is being closed as their is already a new value so it is cancelled. the last value is not being cancelled since there is no new value so it can send all of the values inside of its containing array. is that correct?